# Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.t40hoV (%build) - Mesa

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild, mesa

I am trying to build specific versions of Mesa that have llvm10 for a specific purpose. Downloaded the srpm from a dev's repo (https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/xxmitsu/playground/) and from Fedora repo (https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/mesa/20.1.9/1.fc32/src/). I am doing it on Fedora 34 and am building for the same distro. I have tried both mock and rpmbuild. In both these cases, I have the same error.

This is the spec file I am using:-

```
%define package_name mesa
%global build_branch master
%global _default_patch_fuzz 2
%global __meson_auto_features disabled

%global build_repo https://github.com/mesa3d/mesa
%define version_string 21.3.0

%define commit ba74e1be22f646f9639e85b12c7707e96351a075
%global shortcommit %(c=%{commit}; echo ${c:0:7})
%global commit_date 20210129.14
%global gitrel .%{commit_date}.%{shortcommit}


### LTO and debugpackages are not working together
%if 0%{?fedora} >= 27
%global debug_package %{nil}
%endif

%ifnarch s390x
%global with_hardware 1
%global with_vdpau 1
%global with_vaapi 1
%global with_nine 1
%global with_omx 1
%global with_opencl 1
%global base_drivers nouveau,r100,r200
%endif

%ifarch %{ix86} x86_64
%global platform_drivers ,i915,i965
%global with_vmware 1
%global with_xa     1
%global with_zink   1
%global vulkan_drivers intel,amd
%else
%ifnarch s390x
%global vulkan_drivers amd
%endif
%endif

%ifarch %{arm} aarch64
%global with_etnaviv   1
%global with_freedreno 1
%global with_kmsro     1
%global with_lima      1
%global with_panfrost  1
%global with_tegra     1
%global with_vc4       1
%global with_xa        1
%endif

%ifnarch %{arm} s390x
%global with_radeonsi 1
%global with_iris     1
%endif

%ifnarch %{x86}
%global with_asm 1
%endif

%ifarch %{valgrind_arches}
%bcond_without valgrind
%else
%bcond_with valgrind
%endif

%global with_vulkan_overlay 1

%global dri_drivers %{?base_drivers}%{?platform_drivers}

%global sanitize 1


Name:           %{package_name}
Summary:        Mesa 3D Graphics Library, git version
Version:        %{version_string}
Release:        0.3%{?gitrel}%{?dist}

License:        MIT
URL:            http://www.mesa3d.org

Source0:        %{build_repo}/archive/%{commit}.tar.gz#/mesa-%{commit}.tar.gz
# src/gallium/auxiliary/postprocess/pp_mlaa* have an ... interestingly worded license.
# Source1 contains email correspondence clarifying the license terms.
# Fedora opts to ignore the optional part of clause 2 and treat that code as 2 clause BSD.
Source1:        Mesa-MLAA-License-Clarification-Email.txt

Patch3:         0003-evergreen-big-endian.patch


# Disable rgb10 configs by default:
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1560481
#Patch7:         0001-gallium-Disable-rgb10-configs-by-default.patch

BuildRequires:  meson >= 0.45
BuildRequires:  gcc
BuildRequires:  gcc-c++
BuildRequires:  gettext

%if 0%{?with_hardware}
BuildRequires:  kernel-headers
%endif
%ifarch %{ix86} x86_64
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libdrm_intel) >= 2.4.75
%endif
%if 0%{?with_radeonsi}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libdrm_amdgpu) >= 2.4.97
%endif
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libdrm_radeon) >= 2.4.71
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libdrm_nouveau) >= 2.4.66
%if 0%{?with_etnaviv}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libdrm_etnaviv) >= 2.4.89
%endif
%if 0%{?with_vc4}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libdrm) >= 2.4.89
%endif
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(expat)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(zlib) >= 1.2.3
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libselinux)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(wayland-scanner)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(wayland-protocols) >= 1.8
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(wayland-client) >= 1.11
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(wayland-server) >= 1.11
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(wayland-egl-backend) >= 3
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(x11)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xext)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xdamage) >= 1.1
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xfixes)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb-glx) >= 1.8.1
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xxf86vm)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(x11-xcb)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb-dri2) >= 1.8
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb-dri3)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb-present)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb-sync)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xshmfence) >= 1.1
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(dri2proto) >= 2.8
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(glproto) >= 1.4.14
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb-xfixes)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xcb-randr)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(xrandr) >= 1.3
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libunwind)
BuildRequires:  bison
BuildRequires:  flex
%if 0%{?with_vdpau}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(vdpau) >= 1.1
%endif
%if 0%{?with_vaapi}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libva) >= 0.38.0
%endif
%if 0%{?with_omx}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libomxil-bellagio)
%endif
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libelf)
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libglvnd) >= 0.2.0
BuildRequires:  llvm-devel >= 7.0.0
%if 0%{?with_opencl}
BuildRequires:  clang-devel
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(libclc)
%endif
%if %{with valgrind}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(valgrind)
%endif
BuildRequires:  python3-devel
BuildRequires:  python3-mako
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
BuildRequires:  vulkan-headers
%endif
## vulkan hud requires
%if 0%{?with_vulkan_overlay}
BuildRequires:  glslang
BuildRequires:  lm_sensors-devel
BuildRequires:  /usr/bin/pathfix.py
%endif 
%if 0%{?with_zink}
BuildRequires:  pkgconfig(vulkan)
%endif

%description
%{summary}.

%package filesystem
Summary:        Mesa driver filesystem
Provides:       mesa-dri-filesystem = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Obsoletes:      mesa-dri-filesystem < %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description filesystem
%{summary}.

%package libGL
Summary:        Mesa libGL runtime libraries
Requires:       %{name}-libglapi%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Requires:       libglvnd-glx%{?_isa} >= 1:1.0.1-0.6.99

%description libGL
%{summary}.

%package libGL-devel
Summary:        Mesa libGL development package
Requires:       %{name}-libGL%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Requires:       libglvnd-devel%{?_isa}
Provides:       libGL-devel
Provides:       libGL-devel%{?_isa}

%description libGL-devel
%{summary}.

%package libEGL
Summary:        Mesa libEGL runtime libraries
Requires:       libglvnd-egl%{?_isa}
Obsoletes:      egl-icd < %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description libEGL
%{summary}.

%package libEGL-devel
Summary:        Mesa libEGL development package
Requires:       %{name}-libEGL%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Requires:       libglvnd-devel%{?_isa}
Requires:       %{name}-khr-devel%{?_isa}
Provides:       libEGL-devel
Provides:       libEGL-devel%{?_isa}

%description libEGL-devel
%{summary}.

%package dri-drivers
Summary:        Mesa-based DRI drivers
Requires:       %{name}-filesystem%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description dri-drivers
%{summary}.

%if 0%{?with_omx}
%package omx-drivers
Summary:        Mesa-based OMX drivers
Requires:       %{name}-filesystem%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description omx-drivers
%{summary}.
%endif

%if 0%{?with_vdpau}
%package        vdpau-drivers
Summary:        Mesa-based VDPAU drivers
Requires:       %{name}-filesystem%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description vdpau-drivers
%{summary}.
%endif

%package libOSMesa
Summary:        Mesa offscreen rendering libraries
Requires:       %{name}-libglapi%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Provides:       libOSMesa
Provides:       libOSMesa%{?_isa}

%description libOSMesa
%{summary}.

%package libOSMesa-devel
Summary:        Mesa offscreen rendering development package
Requires:       %{name}-libOSMesa%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description libOSMesa-devel
%{summary}.

%package libgbm
Summary:        Mesa gbm runtime library
Provides:       libgbm
Provides:       libgbm%{?_isa}

%description libgbm
%{summary}.

%package libgbm-devel
Summary:        Mesa libgbm development package
Requires:       %{name}-libgbm%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Provides:       libgbm-devel
Provides:       libgbm-devel%{?_isa}

%description libgbm-devel
%{summary}.

%if 0%{?with_xa}
%package libxatracker
Summary:        Mesa XA state tracker
Provides:       libxatracker
Provides:       libxatracker%{?_isa}

%description libxatracker
%{summary}.

%package libxatracker-devel
Summary:        Mesa XA state tracker development package
Requires:       %{name}-libxatracker%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Provides:       libxatracker-devel
Provides:       libxatracker-devel%{?_isa}

%description libxatracker-devel
%{summary}.
%endif

%package libglapi
Summary:        Mesa shared glapi
Provides:       libglapi
Provides:       libglapi%{?_isa}

%description libglapi
%{summary}.

%if 0%{?with_opencl}
%package libOpenCL
Summary:        Mesa OpenCL runtime library
Requires:       ocl-icd%{?_isa}
Requires:       libclc%{?_isa}
Requires:       %{name}-libgbm%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Requires:       opencl-filesystem

%description libOpenCL
%{summary}.

%package libOpenCL-devel
Summary:        Mesa OpenCL development package
Requires:       %{name}-libOpenCL%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description libOpenCL-devel
%{summary}.
%endif

%if 0%{?with_nine}
%package libd3d
Summary:        Mesa Direct3D9 state tracker

%description libd3d
%{summary}.

%package libd3d-devel
Summary:        Mesa Direct3D9 state tracker development package
Requires:       %{name}-libd3d%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}

%description libd3d-devel
%{summary}.
%endif

%package vulkan-drivers
Summary:        Mesa Vulkan drivers
Requires:       vulkan%{_isa}

%description vulkan-drivers
The drivers with support for the Vulkan API.

%package vulkan-devel
Summary:        Mesa Vulkan development files
Requires:       %{name}-vulkan-drivers%{?_isa} = %{?epoch:%{epoch}:}%{version}-%{release}
Requires:       vulkan-devel

%description vulkan-devel
Headers for development with the Vulkan API.

%prep
%setup -q -c
%autosetup -n mesa-%{commit} -p1
cp %{SOURCE1} docs/

%build

## enable LTO
export CFLAGS="%{build_cflags}"
export CXXFLAGS="%{build_cxxflags}"
export LDFLAGS="%{build_ldflags}"

LTO_FLAGS="-fcommon -g0 -ffat-lto-objects -flto-odr-type-merging"
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -falign-functions=32 -fno-semantic-interposition $LTO_FLAGS "
export FCFLAGS="$CFLAGS -falign-functions=32 -fno-semantic-interposition $LTO_FLAGS "
export FFLAGS="$CFLAGS -falign-functions=32 -fno-semantic-interposition $LTO_FLAGS "
export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++14 -falign-functions=32 -fno-semantic-interposition $LTO_FLAGS "
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAG0S -flto=8 "

%meson -Dcpp_std=gnu++14 \
  -D platforms=x11,wayland \
  -D dri-drivers=%{?dri_drivers} \
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
  -D gallium-drivers=swrast,virgl,r300,nouveau%{?with_vmware:,svga}%{?with_radeonsi:,radeonsi,r600}%{?with_iris:,iris}%{?with_freedreno:,freedreno}%{?with_etnaviv:,etnaviv}%{?with_tegra:,tegra}%{?with_vc4:,vc4}%{?with_kmsro:,kmsro}%{?with_lima:,lima}%{?with_panfrost:,panfrost}%{?with_zink:,zink} \
%else
  -D gallium-drivers=swrast,virgl \
%endif
  -D vulkan-drivers=%{?vulkan_drivers} \
  -D dri3=enabled \
  -D egl=enabled \
  -D gallium-extra-hud=%{?with_gallium_extra_hud:true}%{!?with_gallium_extra_hud:false} \
  -D gallium-nine=%{?with_nine:true}%{!?with_nine:false} \
  -D gallium-omx=%{?with_omx:bellagio}%{!?with_omx:disabled} \
  -D gallium-va=%{?with_vaapi:true}%{!?with_vaapi:false} \
  -D gallium-vdpau=%{?with_vdpau:enabled}%{!?with_vdpau:disabled} \
  -D gallium-xa=enabled \
  -D gallium-xvmc=disabled \
  -D gbm=enabled \
  -D gles1=disabled \
  -D gles2=enabled \
  -D glvnd=true \
  -D glx=dri \
  -D libunwind=true \
  -D llvm=true \
  -Dshared-llvm=true \
  -Dvalgrind=%{?with_valgrind:true}%{!?with_valgrind:false} \
  -Dbuild-tests=false \
  -Dselinux=true \
  -D lmsensors=true \
  -D osmesa=true \
  -D shared-glapi=enabled \
  -D gallium-opencl=%{?with_opencl:icd}%{!?with_opencl:disabled} \
  -D vulkan-layers=device-select%{?with_vulkan_overlay:,overlay} \
  -D tools=[]
  %{nil}
%meson_build

%install
%meson_install

# libvdpau opens the versioned name, don't bother including the unversioned
rm -vf %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/vdpau/*.so
# likewise glvnd
rm -vf %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/libGLX_mesa.so
rm -vf %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/libEGL_mesa.so
# XXX can we just not build this
rm -vf %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/libGLES*

# glvnd needs a default provider for indirect rendering where it cannot
# determine the vendor
ln -s %{_libdir}/libGLX_mesa.so.0 %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/libGLX_system.so.0

# this keeps breaking, check it early.  note that the exit from eu-ftr is odd.
pushd %{buildroot}%{_libdir}
for i in libOSMesa*.so libGL.so ; do
    eu-findtextrel $i && exit 1
done
popd

%files filesystem
%doc docs/Mesa-MLAA-License-Clarification-Email.txt
%dir %{_libdir}/dri
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
%if 0%{?with_vdpau}
%dir %{_libdir}/vdpau
%endif
%endif

%files libGL
%{_libdir}/libGLX_mesa.so.0*
%{_libdir}/libGLX_system.so.0*
%files libGL-devel
%{_includedir}/GL/*
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/dri.pc
%{_libdir}/libglapi.so


%files libEGL
%{_datadir}/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/50_mesa*.json
%{_libdir}/libEGL_mesa.so.0*
%files libEGL-devel
%dir %{_includedir}/EGL
%{_includedir}/EGL/eglmesaext.h
%{_includedir}/EGL/eglextchromium.h

%ldconfig_scriptlets libglapi
%files libglapi
%{_libdir}/libglapi.so.0
%{_libdir}/libglapi.so.0.*

%ldconfig_scriptlets libOSMesa
%files libOSMesa
%{_libdir}/libOSMesa.so.8*
%files libOSMesa-devel
%dir %{_includedir}/GL
%{_includedir}/GL/osmesa.h
%{_libdir}/libOSMesa.so
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/osmesa.pc

%ldconfig_scriptlets libgbm
%files libgbm
%{_libdir}/libgbm.so.1
%{_libdir}/libgbm.so.1.*
%files libgbm-devel
%{_libdir}/libgbm.so
%{_includedir}/gbm.h
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/gbm.pc

%if 0%{?with_xa}
%ldconfig_scriptlets libxatracker
%files libxatracker
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
%{_libdir}/libxatracker.so.2
%{_libdir}/libxatracker.so.2.*
%endif

%files libxatracker-devel
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
%{_libdir}/libxatracker.so
%{_includedir}/xa_tracker.h
%{_includedir}/xa_composite.h
%{_includedir}/xa_context.h
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/xatracker.pc
%endif
%endif

%if 0%{?with_opencl}
%ldconfig_scriptlets libOpenCL
%files libOpenCL
%{_libdir}/libMesaOpenCL.so.*
%{_sysconfdir}/OpenCL/vendors/mesa.icd
%files libOpenCL-devel
%{_libdir}/libMesaOpenCL.so
%endif

%if 0%{?with_nine}
%files libd3d
%dir %{_libdir}/d3d/
%{_libdir}/d3d/*.so.*

%files libd3d-devel
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/d3d.pc
%{_includedir}/d3dadapter/
%{_libdir}/d3d/*.so
%endif

%files dri-drivers
%dir %{_datadir}/drirc.d
%{_datadir}/drirc.d/00-mesa-defaults.conf
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
%{_libdir}/dri/radeon_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/r200_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/nouveau_vieux_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/r300_dri.so
%if 0%{?with_radeonsi}
%{_libdir}/dri/r600_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
%endif
%ifarch %{ix86} x86_64
%{_libdir}/dri/i830_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/i915_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/i965_dri.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_vc4}
%{_libdir}/dri/vc4_dri.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_freedreno}
%{_libdir}/dri/kgsl_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/msm_dri.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_etnaviv}
%{_libdir}/dri/etnaviv_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/imx-drm_dri.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_tegra}
%{_libdir}/dri/tegra_dri.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_lima}
%{_libdir}/dri/lima_dri.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_panfrost}
%{_libdir}/dri/panfrost_dri.so
%endif
%{_libdir}/dri/nouveau_dri.so
%if 0%{?with_vmware}
%{_libdir}/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so
%endif
%{_libdir}/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so
%if 0%{?with_radeonsi}
%{_libdir}/dri/r600_drv_video.so
%{_libdir}/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_iris}
%{_libdir}/dri/iris_dri.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_zink}
%{_libdir}/dri/zink_dri.so
%endif
%endif
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
%dir %{_libdir}/gallium-pipe
%{_libdir}/gallium-pipe/*.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_kmsro}
%{_libdir}/dri/armada-drm_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/exynos_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/hx8357d_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/ili9225_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/ili9341_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/meson_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/mi0283qt_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/pl111_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/repaper_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/rockchip_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/st7586_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/st7735r_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/sun4i-drm_dri.so
%endif
%{_libdir}/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/swrast_dri.so
%{_libdir}/dri/virtio_gpu_dri.so

%if 0%{?with_hardware}
%if 0%{?with_omx}
%files omx-drivers
%{_libdir}/bellagio/libomx_mesa.so
%endif
%if 0%{?with_vdpau}
%files vdpau-drivers
%{_libdir}/vdpau/libvdpau_nouveau.so.1*
%{_libdir}/vdpau/libvdpau_r300.so.1*
%if 0%{?with_radeonsi}
%{_libdir}/vdpau/libvdpau_r600.so.1*
%{_libdir}/vdpau/libvdpau_radeonsi.so.1*
%endif
%endif
%endif

%files vulkan-drivers
%if 0%{?with_hardware}
%ifarch %{ix86} x86_64
%{_libdir}/libvulkan_intel.so
%{_datadir}/vulkan/icd.d/intel_icd.*.json
%endif
%{_libdir}/libvulkan_radeon.so
%{_datadir}/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.*.json
%endif
%if 0%{?with_vulkan_overlay}
%{_bindir}/mesa-overlay-control.py
%{_libdir}/libVkLayer_MESA_overlay.so
%{_datadir}/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_MESA_overlay.json
%endif
%{_libdir}/libVkLayer_MESA_device_select.so
%{_datadir}/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/VkLayer_MESA_device_select.json

%files vulkan-devel


%changelog
* Tue Jun 15 2021 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Partially revert the modifications done in Apr 11:
- Regenerate vulkan-devel package but with no files
- This provides a lean upgrade path

* Wed May 05 2021 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- After https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/merge_requests/10554
- also consider i830_dri.so

* Sun Apr 11 2021 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Don't generate a separate vulkan-devel package anymore
- Since upstream commit:
-    commit 5e6db1916860ec217eac60903e0a9d10189d1c53
-    Author: Chad Versace <chad@kiwitree.net>
-    Message:
-       anv: Remove vkCreateDmaBufINTEL (v4)

* Fri Mar 26 2021 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Set vulkan-layers=device-select,overlay since upstream commit 54fe5b04

* Fri Dec 11 2020 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Set osmesa=true since upstream commit ee802372180a2b4460cc7abb53438e45c6b6f1e4 

* Wed Nov 25 2020 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- meson: __meson_auto_features default to disabled
- Issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/3873

* Mon Nov 23 2020 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- meson: drop deprecated EGL platform build options.
- Consequence of MR: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/merge_requests/5844

* Mon Apr 20 2020 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Enable vulkan-device-select-layer.

* Sun Feb 09 2020 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Enable zink.

* Sat Feb 08 2020 Mikhail Gavrilov <mikhail.v.gavrilov@gmail.com>
- Prevent radeonsi crashing when compiled with GCC10 on Rawhide.

* Thu Jan 23 2020 Tom Stellard <tstellar@redhat.com>
- Link against libclang-cpp.so
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Stop-Shipping-Individual-Component-Libraries-In-clang-lib-Package

* Sat Dec 14 2019 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- new mesa-overlay-control.py script added to the install list

* Sun Nov 03 2019 Peter Robinson <pbrobinson@gmail.com>
- adjust mesa-khr-devel requires now provided by libglvnd

* Sun Oct 06 2019 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Architecture specific builds might run asynchronous.
- This might cause that same package build for x86_64 will be different when
-  built for i686. This is problematic when we want to install multilib packages. 
- Convert the specfile to template and use it to generate the actual script.
- This will prevent the random failues and mismatch between arch versions.

* Sun Sep 08 2019 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Merge the two implementations.

* Sun Jul 07 2019 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Implement some version autodetection to reduce maintenance work.

* Thu Jul 04 2019 Mihai Vultur <xanto@egaming.ro>
- Modified to point to Valve's Radeon ACO compiler patches from https://github.com/daniel-schuermann/mesa.

* Mon Oct 10 2016 Rudolf Kastl <rudolf@redhat.com>
- Synced with Leighs spec.
```

And, here is the tmp file - https://pastebin.com/PGa9hMXD (word limit here).
Can anybody tell me where the trouble is?

Comment: What's the actual error? There should be something above the "Bad exit status" message.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried rpmbuild on Fedora 32 and it worked. But, when I tried to build the 32 bit RPMs, I get this error -

`Checking if "dep-clang-usable" with dependencies LLVM, -lclang-cpp runs: DID NOT COMPILE`

`src/gallium/targets/opencl/meson.build:62:2: ERROR: C++ shared or static library 'clangCodeGen' not found`

Comment: Are you doing a 32 bit build on a 32 bit os (virtualize/container is okay too)? The way rpm/rpmbuild work, trying to build for 32 bit on 64 bit machines is going to cause you endless grief. It's something to avoid unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, I am using a 64 bit Fedora 32 for this. The 64 bit RPMs were built without issues using RPMbuild. But,32 bit RPMs can't be built. I don't have another alternative as F32 doesn't support 32 bit OS. And, if I try Mock, it isn't able to download the root files for 32 bit - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69145396/mock-fails-to-download-disable-plugin-patterns-while-building-32bit-rpms-403-on