# Mock fails to download disable plugin patterns while building 32bit RPMs: 403 on repository 'local'

Tags: fedora, rpm

I am trying to build a few RPMs for 32 bit Fedora using the SRPM. I tried running Mock with:-

```
mock -r fedora-32-i386 rebuild src.rpm
```

It gives me the following error:

```
No matches found for the following disable plugin patterns: local, spacewalk
local                                           83  B/s | 199  B     00:02    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'local':
  - Status code: 403 for https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/repos/f32-build/latest/i386/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 38.145.60.21)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'local': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
ERROR: Command failed: 
 # /usr/bin/dnf --installroot /var/lib/mock/fedora-32-i686-bootstrap/root/ --releasever 32 --setopt=deltarpm=False --allowerasing --disableplugin=local --disableplugin=spacewalk install dnf dnf-plugins-core --setopt=tsflags=nocontexts
No matches found for the following disable plugin patterns: local, spacewalk
local                                           83  B/s | 199  B     00:02    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'local':
  - Status code: 403 for https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/repos/f32-build/latest/i386/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 38.145.60.21)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'local': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

I have tried disabling the fastest mirror in the conf file in /etc/dnf, with no luck. Is mock using a different repo file than my current installation? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Mock is using configs from the directory `/etc/mock/` so for `fedora-32-i386` it is `/etc/mock/fedora-32-i386.cfg` This config contains yum config which is used during the installation of the buildroot.

More about Mock's configs: https://rpm-software-management.github.io/mock/configuration